# How to retrieve a finished report from Adobe Analytics using RSiteCatalyst

Tags: r, adobe-analytics

I just started using the R package RSiteCatalyst to access Adobe Analytics via the reporting API.

By using this package I can retrieve data and build a report the way I need it. However, I was wondering if it is possible to create a report in Adobe Analytics, assign it a `report_id` and then access the report via R with the `report_id`.

I have looked at the predefined functions, but they don't seem to help. I thought `getReport` or `getDashboard` are the ones, but they seem to be doing something else.

Does anybody know? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe refer to this question as the solution might work for you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276766/r-3-4-1-intelligent-use-of-while-loop-for-rsitecatalyst-enqueued-reports/58530703#58530703

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you can use the predefined function `getReport`.

This worked fine for me:

```
GetReport(11111111, interval.seconds = 10, max.attempts = 3,
          print.attempts = TRUE)
```