# how to pull data directly into R from Adobe Analtics using Queue DataWarehouse function in RSiteCatalyst package?

Tags: r, api, data-warehouse, information-retrieval, adobe-analytics

I am trying to pull data from Adobe Analytics using the API in the R package RSiteCatalyst but am having trouble pulling the data directly into R. This is the code I am using:

```
QueueDataWarehouse('report_suite', Sys.Date()-30, Sys.Date(), c("metric1", 
                   "metric2", "metric3", "metric4"), 
                   c("dimension1"), 
                   date.granularity = "day", data.current = TRUE,
                   expedite = FALSE, 
                   interval.seconds = 120*60, max.attempts =1 ,
                   validate = TRUE, enqueueOnly = FALSE)
```

I have set the interval.seconds to 2 hours because it takes a while to run, just the problem is it always times out. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276766/r-3-4-1-intelligent-use-of-while-loop-for-rsitecatalyst-enqueued-reports/58530703#58530703

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R 3.4.1 - Intelligent use of while loop for RSiteCatalyst enqueued reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276766/r-3-4-1-intelligent-use-of-while-loop-for-rsitecatalyst-enqueued-reports)

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to realize with `QueueDataWarehouse` is that its performance is solely dependent on the speed that Adobe Data Warehouse returns an answer. The way you are running the code here, you are gambling that Data Warehouse will return the answer within 2 hours, which may not be feasible depending on the amount of data requested, other reports in the queue, etc.

If you are timing out after two hours, I would suggest writing to an FTP, then picking the report up there.